# Reshape data with header rows

Tags: r, tidyr

I have data in this form, where a separate column is included in a separate row at the start of group of detail records

```
data <- data.frame(detail = c("", "Sue", "Fred", "", "Jayne", "Harold", "Jim"),
                   group = c("Group 1", "", "", "Group 2", "", "", ""))
```

I want to reshape it as follows. Can this be done with pivot_wider?

| Detail | Group No |
| --- | --- |
| Sue | Group 1 |
| Fred | Group 1 |
| Jayne | Group 2 |
| Harold | Group 2 |
| Jim | Group 2 |

Answer (score 0):

here is a data.table approach

```
library(data.table)
# set to data.table fotmat
setDT(data)
# set "" as NA
data[data == ""] <- NA
# fill NA's 
data[, group := zoo::na.locf(group)]
# subset
data[!is.na(detail), ]
# detail   group
# 1:    Sue Group 1
# 2:   Fred Group 1
# 3:  Jayne Group 2
# 4: Harold Group 2
# 5:    Jim Group 2
```